# What types are possible in error_get_last()

Tags: php

I'm searching for a list of possible "**types**" of errors in [`error_get_last()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php)

For instance the method returns this array:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 1
    [message] => Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes)
    [file] => /dir/file.php
    [line] => 123
)
```

So I assume "**1**" is a "**Fatal Error**"

What are the others?

Comment: From the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php): [See Also ¶

Error constants](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

Comment: Please, RTFM > http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Comment: ok ok, calm down. I was searching but didn't find it. Thanks guys!

Comment: I don't think the documentation is pretty clear about the origin of the types.

Comment: @revaxarts I tried searching this in php.net and Google and couldn't find what I wanted either, until Google returned this question and answer. So this question is good, and suggesting to "RTFM" is not, as now Stack provides a good answer and is top of Google results for such searches. This is good for the site! +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These types are just the [php error constants](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).